# How can I reverse the output of my array when given an input of random numbers generated by the computer?

Tags: c++, arrays, random, reverse

The issue I am currently having is that my code creates and prints 40 numbers into an array.  When attempting to print this set of code backwards it will only print the final number in the regular/normal array when I need it to print the entire first array in reverse order.  Thanks for the help.  I am using c++.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    int i;
    int lower = 0, upper = 100; //Random number between 1 and 100 is generated
    int rand_num; 
    int num[40];

    srand(time(0)); 

    printf("Your array is shown:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        rand_num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        num[rand_num] = rand_num;

        printf("%d ",num[rand_num]);

    }


    printf("\nYour array backwards is:\n");
    for(i = 39; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ", num[rand_num]);

    }


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: are you using c++?

Comment: Yes sorry for not stating earlier

Comment: Think carefully about what `num[rand_num]` means.  I am pretty sure all occurrences of it are not what you want.

Comment: If the inputs are truly random, how would anyone know if you DIDN'T reverse the array?

Comment: `num[rand_num]` seems a bit off.

Comment: @user4581301 Because the OP shows the array before and after the reversing.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `for` loop change this `num[rand_num] = rand_num` for `num[i] = rand_num` and `printf("%d ", num[rand_num])` for `printf("%d", num[i])`.

In your second `for` loop change `printf("%d ", num[rand_num])` for `printf("%d", num[i])`.

The issue was in your `for` loops as you can see. You were not making use of your iteration variable `i` to index into the `num` array, instead you were indexing it always with `rand_num` which is a random number, and specifically, in your last `for` loop it didn't change, so it was displaying `num[rand_num]` in every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your use of `num[rand_num]`. That means your access of the array is controlled by a random number, and not `i`.

The solution is simple: replace every instance of `num[rand_num]` with `num[i]`.